# What pattern to use, when relating objects by composition, to facilitate communication between the objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Say I have a python class: Foo(), that has a member self.bar which is assigned at initialisation of Foo() to be an instance of Bar(). So something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()
        self.other_member = 0
```

Then say I bind some method of Bar() to a signal/callback and when triggered (externally) I want it to make a change to some other member of Foo().

My question is: is this a crazy thing to want to do? And if not, is there an advised pattern to follow when implementing something like this?

Comment: the called method of `Bar`, is it a member method?

Comment: What is their actual, real-world relationship? There are a lot of options, like making `Bar`s able to emit events too and adding a listener to `self.bar`.

Comment: @Samha’ — yes it’s a member method of Bar() that is triggered.

Comment: when u call a member method of `Bar` object, u are breaking `encapsulation`. May be u can tell us what are the restrictions, and then we can provide better solution.

Comment: @Ry — Foo() is an instance of an animal species and Bar() is an object representing a trait that the species may have. That trait means that in certain circumstances (represented by the event/signal), an effect, (which is proper to the trait, and indirectly also to the species now that the species has this trait) occurs that impacts the animal species. Not sure if that’s clear but of course very happy to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `Inheritance` to establish `Trait` behavior, and register newly-created `container objects` to `Trait static variables`.

**In this example:**

- Parent `class Trait` is where all the logic resides.
- Define **trait specific behavior** in `child classes` inheriting from `Trait`, e.g `Trait_Meow`.
- Use **composition** to tie each `animal class` to its `traits`.
- U can reference the `container` objects of *class Cat* from inside `trait` events *(methods)* using `self.animal()`.

```py
from weakref import WeakSet, ref as weakref

class Trait:
  def register_animal(self):
    try:
      self.__class__.live_animals.add(self)
    except AttributeError as e:
      self.__class__.live_animals = WeakSet([self])

  def __init__(self, animal):
    self.animal = weakref(animal)
    self.register_animal()

class Trait_Meow(Trait):
  def meow(self):
    print('{} says: meoooooow'.format(self.animal().name))

  def all_meow():
    for animal in Trait_Meow.live_animals:
      animal.meow()

class Cat:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.traits = set([Trait_Meow(self)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cat1 = Cat('cat1')
  cat2 = Cat('cat2')

  Trait_Meow.all_meow()

# output
# cat2 says: meoooooow
# cat1 says: meoooooow
```

Comment: This is actually quite similar to what I initially implemented with a couple of differences — using “weakref” is presumably better here as it allows the objects to be garbage collected, whereas without this we’d have the two objects holding reference to each other and they’d never get GC’d?

Comment: The other difference, is that I had tried to use type hints but this introduced an import cycle between the “trait” and “species” classes. Should I just then abandon type hints in this case, or is there a way around that?

Comment: I think we need to use
    weakref.proxy(animal)
rather than weakref(), right? Otherwise it looks like I can't call methods on the object (I get an error about a weakref object not supporting the called method).

Comment: Hi Ben. Really excellent question. Regarding type hints, the recommended way to solve the type hinting criss-cross problem that you described, which is also called the problem of forward references, is to define the type using a string literal. See PEP 484 here: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references

Comment: @Ben `weakref.ref` is enough actually to access `species` methods. U may have forgotten to put `()` after the `weakref object` like this `self.animal().do_species_behavior()`.
Needless to mention that it may not be a good design to call `species` methods from inside trait methods. I suggest incorporating shared methods into the corresponding `trait_sublcass`.